Relation between the second derivative and the second degree polynomial approximation
Let E $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $a$ be a limit point of $E$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f, h: E \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions such that $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + c(x - a)^2 + h(x)$ for all $x \in E$.
Does $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{h(x)}{(x-a)^2} = 0$ imply that $f'$ is differentiable at $a$ and that $c = \frac{f''(a)}{2}$? If not, what extra conditions need to be added to prove that $f'$ is differentiable at $a$?
Attempt thus far:
$f'(x) = f'(a) + 2c(x - a) + h'(x)$
$\frac{f'(x) - f'(a)}{x - a} = 2c + \frac{h'(x)}{x - a}$
$h(a) = h'(a) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{h(x)}{(x-a)^2} = 0$
What's missing is proving that $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{h'(x)}{x - a} = 0$ if proving it is possible.

For the first part of your question the answer is "no".  The existence of the Taylor development at $a$ of order $2$ does not imply that $f$ need to be two time differentiable.  The equivalence holds true only at order $1$.
For a counterexample, let $a = 0$.  Take the real function defined by
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^{5/2} \sin\frac{1}{x} & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
0  & \text{if not}. 
\end{cases}
$$
Then its Taylor polynomial of degree $2$ is $0$ and we see easily that $f'(0) = 0$ and that $f'$ is not differentiable at $0$, since for $x \neq 0$,
$$
f'(x) = \frac{5}{2}x\sqrt{x}\sin\frac{1}{x} -\sqrt{x}\cos\frac{1}{x}.
$$
Remark. The last assertion in your post is not true.  In the above example $h = f$ and $h'(x)/x$ has no limit at $0$.
